# round a number up and use log in python

Tags: python, math

I have the following number - 191897378

I want to turn this into 192 representing 192 million. I have tried ceil(191897378) and using a log but I am going horribly wrong here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Divide it first!

Comment: genius thanks,  sorry I was being a right wally

Comment: You have to show your attempt and results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x = 191897378/1000000
round(x)
```